# PHP - Imagick - bad quality after resizing

Tags: php, resize, imagick

I have got this image (900x900, .jpg) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhQs0.jpg

I resized it to 290x290 and i got this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1aqR.jpg

This is my PHP code :

```
$thumb_large = new \Imagick($path);
$thumb_large->setImageFormat( 'jpeg' );
$thumb_large->setResolution(900,900);
$thumb_large->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$thumb_large->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$thumb_large->adaptiveResizeImage($value[0], $value[1]);
$thumb_large->writeImage(public_path() . '/uploads/images/'.$key.'/' . $file_name);
```

What am i doing wrong? The quality is horrible.

Comment: Just curios... Why not use `$imagick->thumbnailImage` ?

Comment: Easy: Read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php

Answer (score 2):

> The quality is horrible.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.adaptiveresizeimage.php):

> Adaptively resize image with data-dependent triangulation. Avoids blurring across sharp color changes. Most useful when used to shrink images slightly to a slightly smaller "web size"; **may not look good when a full-sized image is adaptively resized to a thumbnail**.

I suggest using [Imagick::resizeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php)  with `Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS`.

Comment: It still looks like shit with `Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS`.